# Is it possible to Quit Porn and Masturbation?

Tags: mental-health, psychologist-psychology, psychiatrist-psychiatry

I understand there are dozens of websites out there which provide advice but I have been watching videos that claim watching **porn changes connections in your brain what I could gather from the videos was that some changes could be permanent**.

Is it possible to quit porn and masturbation and get my brain back to what it was?

I started at an early age due to shitty reasons, I masturbated watched a lot of porn since I was 12 or 13 years old.Is it too late for fixing the problem?
I have spoken to a psychologist but I just feel too embarrassed to tell him all my 'habits', In the initial sessions he said it was not anything dangerous.
If anybody knows of any portals where I can hide my identity and talk to someone please share I need help :(

Comment: Is this suitable for Health.SE? Especially with @teahill  answer, which answers the question perfectly though, it seems to me that this is not really a question regarding health.

Comment: This [ted talk](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wSF82AwSDiU) might provide you with more information.

Comment: The original poster wrote: "porn changes connections in your brain". The issue has been affecting his mental health and self esteem. Possible addictions are indeed health-related.

Comment: @tealhill Convinced. Maybe your answer could include the addiction and health (neural) aspects of the question. That's what partly startled me and made me thinking.

Comment: Nah. Feel free to edit my answer though!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably difficult but possible to quit. Here's a [case report](http://www.mayoclinicproceedings.org/article/S0025-6196(11)60846-X/fulltext) of a guy who was severely addicted. He spent up to 8 hours a day online, watching pornography, and lost several jobs due to addiction. He needed help from a psychiatrist, but did manage to get sexually sober. If he quit, you can too. :)

An Internet filter might help. Pluckeye is good. Or you can use a parental-control filter and have a friend hold the password.

Buy iOS devices, not Android devices. They're easier to filter.

Don't sleep with a cellphone next to your bed.

Keep a window shade open behind you when you're on the computer. That way, people can see in. Fear of being caught might help.

The [Pornfree sub-Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pornfree/) might also be helpful. Visit and post every day.